# How do I get the unique months per year from a list?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of different events called `events`. This contains the date of an event. I want to get all the unique years and months. This should be sorted in ascending order.

What I would like to have:

```
unique = {
"2023":[
  "January", "October"],
"2024":[
  "March"]
}
```

My input array:

```js
events = [
    {
        "eventid": 6,
        "name": "Event 1",
        "description": "This is the first event.",
        "date": "10.10.2023",
        "status": "XO"
    },
    {
        "eventid": 8,
        "name": "Event 2",
        "description": "This is another event",
        "date": "14.01.2023",
        "status": "XO"
    },
    {
        "eventid": 8,
        "name": "Event 3",
        "description": "This is the last event",
        "date": "14.03.2024",
        "status": "OS"
    }
]
```

Comment: So first step parse a date into month and year. Second step loop over all the items with reduce. If you do not have a year in the object, add a new set. If you have a year, add the month to the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over array, parse date and fill result object, then loop over existing keys, sort values in array and map month number to name. You can map them manually or use US or any other locale to get the month names.

```js
const result = {};
for (let e of events) {
  const [_, m, y] = e.date.split(".")
  const yn = parseInt(y);
  const mn = parseInt(m);

  if (!result[yn]) result[yn] = [];
  if (!result[yn].includes(mn)) result[yn].push(mn)
}

for (let y in result) {
  result[y] = result[y].sort().map(m => new Date(2020, m - 1, 1).toLocaleString("en-US", {
    month: "long"
  }));
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
  const events = [{
      "eventid": 6,
      "name": "Event 1",
      "description": "This is the first event.",
      "date": "10.10.2023",
      "status": "XO"
    },
    {
      "eventid": 8,
      "name": "Event 2",
      "description": "This is another event",
      "date": "14.01.2023",
      "status": "XO"
    },
    {
      "eventid": 8,
      "name": "Event 3",
      "description": "This is the last event",
      "date": "14.03.2024",
      "status": "OS"
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Comment: This also works and is shorter: `for (let e of events) { const [_, m, y] = e.date.split("."); (result[y] = result[y] || []); if (!result[y].includes(m))  result[y].push(m) }` - the -1 later will coerce to number

Comment: True, using numeric keys and values is not neccessary here.

Comment: If the text in the input was ever slightly off, the parsing would never catch it.  But if you're good with that...  cool.

Comment: If the text is off, then the date is wrong. Then they have bigger problems